# How to setup StyleCop for Asp.net Core 1.1 solution?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, stylecop

I'm working on asp.net core project which has a lot of projects (web, console & class library) and I want to setup stylecop for that.

I tried to install "StyleCopAnalyzers" nuget and it seems working (giving stylecop violation error).

some of stylecop rules I want to ignore (e.g. SA1652) for entire solution level.

Need help to setup stylecop for complete solution with best practics.

[image]

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may suppress undesired policies via suppression file. Create this file on solution root folder and link it (`Add as Link`) to each your project.

[image: Create]

Sample file content:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules", "SA1101:Prefix local calls with this")]
[assembly: SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules", "SA1124:Do not use regions")]
```

Comment: I tried above approach but not able to resolve all stylecop issue like SA1005 suppression not working in project level ( [assembly: SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.SpacingRules", "SA1005:Single line comments must begin with single space", Justification = "Pending", Scope = "member", Target = "~M:ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(System.String[])")]). With target it is  working only class but without target Its not working anymore.

Comment: Check https://bitbucket.org/just_dmitry/parsec.vedom (VS2017). If I add `[assembly: SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.SpacingRules", "SA1005:Single line comments must begin with single space")]` to `GlobalSuppression.cs` it works for classes in project (`Startup.cs` for example). VS/Roslyn takes about minute to "catch" saved changes (try to reload solution to be sure), but it works.